# При редактировании сообщения ошибка 400, "Bad Request: MESSAGE_ID_INVALID"

Tags: telegram-bot, telegram

Суть такова: у меня есть канал в телеграмме, к нему подключен бот @discussbot, который автоматически при новом посте в канале, добавляет к нему кнопочку с ссылкой на страницу комментариев. Если смотреть update, то видно что приходит update типа edited_channel_post. Но когда я хочу после этого поменять этот пост с помощью уже своего бота при помощи функции editMessageText или editMessageReplyMarkup, то возвращается ошибка  "Bad Request: MESSAGE_ID_INVALID". Хотя я уверен что id соообщения правильное. Те сообщения в канале, которые @discussbot не трогал спокойно меняются. В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 3):

Кратко [цитирую отсюда](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#updating-messages):

> Please note, that it is currently only possible to edit messages without reply_markup or with inline keyboards.